# Seek REGEX for matching groups with choice of closing String

Tags: java, regex

I have got a String which consists of multiple "new Array(...)" substrings. Each array finishes with ")," except the last one, it finishes with "))".

A sample Strong looks like this:

```
String text="root(new Array(\"Field1\", \"Field2\"), new Array(new Array(\"myArray1F1 (St.)\", \"myArray1F2\"),new Array(\"myArray2F1\", \"myArray2F2\"),new Array(\"myArray3F1\", \"myArray3F2\")) 0, 0)";
```

I tried with several patterns I made up by myself or found in the internet. But nothing works. I started with this pattern and am still wondering, why this does not work.

```
Pattern.compile("(new Array\\(\".*(\\),|\\)\\)))");
```

or

```
Pattern.compile("(new Array\\(\"(?!\\),|\\)\\)).*)");
```

This give back the whole String almost as is.

```
    @Test
    public void testMyArray() {
        Pattern arrayPattern = Pattern.compile("(new Array\\(\".*(\\),|\\)\\)))");
        String text="root(new Array(\"Field1\", \"Field2\"), new Array(new Array(\"myArray1F1 (St.)\", \"myArray1F2\"),new Array(\"myArray2F1\", \"myArray2F2\"),new Array(\"myArray3F1\", \"myArray3F2\")) 0, 0)";
        Matcher matcher = arrayPattern.matcher(text);
        while  (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
```

These are the groups I want to detect:

```
new Array("Field1", "Field2") 
new Array("myArray1F1 (St.)", "myArray1F2") 
new Array("myArray2F1", "myArray2F2") 
new Array("myArray3F1", "myArray3F2")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me.

```java
/* Required imports
 * import java.util.regex.Matcher;
 * import java.util.regex.Pattern;
 */
Pattern pttrn = Pattern.compile("new Array\\(\".+?\"\\),?");
Matcher mtchr = pttrn.matcher(text);
while (mtchr.find()) {
    System.out.println(mtchr.group());
}
```

The pattern looks for text that starts with `new Array(` and followed by a single double quote character which is followed by one or more characters which is followed by another double quote character which is followed by a closing bracket and maybe ending with a single comma.

Note that `+?` is known as a *reluctant qualifier* and `?` means exactly one or none.

The output is

```
new Array("Field1", "Field2"),
new Array("myArray1F1 (St.)", "myArray1F2"),
new Array("myArray2F1", "myArray2F2"),
new Array("myArray3F1", "myArray3F2")
```

Comment: Thanks for it. I like it. But I fixed my problem by plain Java code. Was done within an hour - while I had spend for searching the REGEX more than a day. I will stay with it - for me it seems I can easier modify it when needed, until I get more familiar with REGEX.